# Why can't I use the format function with docstrings?

Tags: python, docstring

I have a function that starts like this:

```
def apply_weighting(self, weighting):
    """
    Available functions: {}
    """.format(weightings)
```

What I want is for the docstring to print the dictionary of available weighting functions. But when inspecting the function it states that there are no docstring available:

```
In [69]: d.apply_weighting?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<bound method DissectSpace.apply_weighting of <dissect.DissectSpace instance at 0x106b74dd0>>
File:       [...]/dissect.py
Definition: d.apply_weighting(self, weighting)
Docstring:  <no docstring>
```

How come? Is it not possible to format a docstring?

Comment: if your docstring is so generic that you can use a formatstrnig on it ... is there any real advantage to having it?

Comment: @JoranBeasley The weightings contains a string -> function dictionary which contains all available weighting functions I can apply. By having them readily available in the docstring, looking up which ones to use is easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Python interpreter looks for string literals *only*. Adding a `.format()` method call is not supported, not for the function definition syntax.  It is the compiler that parses out the docstring, not the interpreter, and any variables like `weightings` are not available at that time; no code execution takes place at this time.

You can always update a docstring after the fact:

```
def apply_weighting(self, weighting):
    """
    Available functions: {}
    """

apply_weighting.__doc__ = apply_weighting.__doc__.format(weightings)
```