# Fstring not being read as a docstring [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem in my code that I can't seem to find a way to fix. I have a custom help command which works fine but when I define the docstring as a fstring it gives `None` as an output

code from my help command:

```
if cmd.help:
  emd.add_field(name=f'{self.client.command_prefix}{cmd}', value=f'{aliases}\n{cmd.help}\u200b', inline=False)
              found_cmd = True
else:
  print(cmd.help)
  emd.add_field(name=f'{self.client.command_prefix}{cmd}', value=f'{aliases}\n - \u200b', inline=False)
```

The roll command I tried the test command:

```
@commands.command()
  async def roll(self, ctx, sides:int = 6, num_of_times_to_roll:int=1):
    f'''syntax:`{self.client.command_prefix}roll [number of sides] [number of times to roll]` \nThis command rolls a die or dice with any number of sides and any number of times \n\n`{self.client.command_prefix}roll_side` \nThis command only takes the number of sides as an input'''
```

I think that python does not read fstrings as docstrings because when I try the help command with normal docstrings it works fine. If anyone knows how to fix this problem please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatted string literals cannot be used as docstrings, even if they do not
include expressions.

example:

```
   >>> def foo():
   ...     f"Not a docstring"
   ...
   >>> foo.__doc__ is None
   True
```

There is a possible solution for you in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838641/13354437)

Answer (score 2):

It's because the python's *f-string* is a runtime facility that inflates the string at **runtime**. On the other hand, *docstrings* are **compile-time** facilities that are parsed even prior to the code being interpreted.
In simple words, you can't benefit from runtime facilities on compile-time, since nothing actually is running!
For more info [this thread](https://itqna.net/questions/3282/why-can-not-f-strings-be-used-docstring) may be helpful.

Comment: @Hiddencoder Yes, actually. In your specific example, the docstring tool even has no idea about the `self` **object**, which is a dynamic runtime object.

Comment: Thanks but the problem has been fixed.